# is there another way to control the bandwidth of a webRTC session other than with sdp?

Tags: javascript, controls, webrtc, bandwidth, sdp

I want to know if there is another way to control the bandwidth of a webRTC session other than modifying sdp parameters.?

I ask this because I have read in some old articles that ORTC will replace the Session Description Protocol (SDP) in webRTC.

It is not possible to control the bandwidth automatically just changing the camera resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum bitrate at which media can be encoded/sent is configurable via the RTCRtpSender objects [maxBitrate property](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-rtcrtpencodingparameters-maxbitrate).

The webrtc samples have [a sample for that](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/js/main.js#L171-L197) since in practice its a bit more tricky due to difference between browsers.

Comment: Hey phillip, thanks for your answer! I have learned a lot just with the information you have sent. I am checking the sample code that you said, and I am certainly noticing that they have two types of modifications, one with ORTC and one with SDP. this is because the difference between browsers that you mention?

Comment: No, Firefox simply has an incomplete implementation of RTCRtpSender.getParameters(). The SDP-based fallback is mainly for (very) old browser versions.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thanks very much Phillip! could you tell me where I can read more information about how to change the bitrate separately for every media? because I noticed in the google's implementation that when I am transferring just video it works good, but when I am transferring both audio and video it has an strange behavior (I think it is confusing the bandwidths, but I am not sure).

Comment: Where cold I read some documentation on how to control the webRTC Audio and Video bandiwdth. Separately in one webRTC session?